# Google Actions Smart Home Simulator Not detecting My Action

Tags: actions-on-google

I am trying to test a very basic home automation action. I have followed all the tutorials etc.

1. Setup OAuth Server
2. Create Action Name
3. Set smart home action url
4. Setup account Linking
5. Test action in simulator

However I am stuck with testing the action in the simulator. I named my action `Testing`.

When I got to simulator, it suggests that I say, "Talk to Testing".  When I do that. It just says `We're sorry, but something went wrong. Please try again.`

[image]

How do I know whats wrong.  I was watching my oAuth Server and no http requests where even made to it. So its not even trying to authenticate.

Answer (score 2):

When you build a smart home action, it's not conversational. Doing "Talk to Testing" would not work as that query does not fit within the standard types of queries that can be made to a smart home action.

To use the simulator for smart home actions, you need to follow the [testing guide](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/testing-deploying).

- Enable testing for the action
- Go to the Google Assistant settings on your phone to do account linking
- After this happens, you can send smart home commands directly through the simulator (not conversational), ie. "turn on my light"

Comment: Do I need to release my action? Because when I do, it says I have to check that it works in the simulator page?

Comment: If it works in the simulator or on a real device, it is fine to submit.